# UITableView lags when implementing infinite scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, instruments

My table scrolls very smoothly normally when the data has been loaded on the screen and I am not loading more, however, I am trying to figure why the table lags when new data is loaded onto the table for approximately 0.5 sec. So I have performed the time profiler hoping to see something blocking the main thread when more data is loaded.

The time profiler indicated that the main thread took up 399ms whilst the other function I implemented only took up 49ms in total. This leaves me no clue to hunt down the cause of that lag. Why would the time profile just give me 399ms on the main function instead of giving me a call tree with how the 399ms came about?

I was wondering if there is a way to track down the cause of my lag while loading for more data?

[image: instrument result]

Comment: Do you load data into cell in willDisplayCell or cellForRow?

Comment: it's actually viewForHeaderInSection that I am using. I dont have any data for cellForRowAtIndexPath yet. And I am using willDIsplayHeaderView to load more when the user scrolled to bottom

Comment: Can you post code of your delegate & datasource.

Comment: I am not looking to go down that path yet as there are thousands of lines that links to some custom classes...etc. So I was hoping more for an explanation of the instrument result (399ms with no way to tell which function is using that other than main?). Or perhaps a way to use instruments differently to find my problem?